# how to returns all records from change tracking in sql?

Tags: sql-server

```sql
SELECT * FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES PROFILE_PERSONAL_TAB, 0) AS CT
```

this query returns only 5 records

```sql
DECLARE @synchronization_version bigint;
SET @synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()-1;
select @synchronization_version
```

1. @synchronization_version is 48
2. When I set @synchronization_version=0 and run below query

```sql
SELECT * FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES PROFILE_PERSONAL_TAB, @synchronization_version) AS CT
```

returns only 5 records. so how to return all records from 0 to 48 ?

Comment: 48 doesn't mean that your table was changed 48 times. Other changes also increment change tracking